# Resolve a path string in native JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file, filepath

I'm trying to resolve a string to a theoretical, virtual path (created all in the client side), using plain old JavaScript, no NodeJS, nothing (and I tried making a new URL or setting the path to a href etc., but I want this to work inside of a web-worker).

Basically, there is a virtual file system, that starts with, say, `"C:/"`, and goes down like every other path system. Let's say I am given a string as an input such as

```
"C:/someDir/someOtherDir/someThirdDir/../../folderInSomeDir/fileInFolderInSomeDir.txt"
```

so this would theoretically be accessing, well, as the name of the file itself says, a file inside of a folder, which itself is inside of the folder named `someDir`.

The hard part to process is the `../../` part, so the expected output string from the above would be

```
"C:/someDir/folderInSomeDir/fileInFolderInSomeDir.txt"
```

I'm just drawing a mental blank as to how exactly to process the `../../` part, I tried splitting up the string by `/` and looping through the sections, determining if the current string is equal to `..`, and also keeping track of the current directory which immediately would precede each `..`, but I'm at a mental blank as to what to do next to get the output string. Here's my function, currently

```js
b.onclick = () => {
  out.innerHTML = resolve(p.value)
};
function resolve(path, basePath = "/") {
                    var pathd = pathify(path)
                    if(basePath != "/") basePath = resolve(basePath)
                    var based = pathify(basePath)
                    var baseDirs = based.split("/")
                    var directs = pathd.split("/")
                    var upDirs = 0
                    var currentDir = ""
                    var numberDirs
          var result
                    directs.forEach((x, i, ar) => {
                        if(x == ".." || i == 0 && x == "") {
                            upDirs++
                        }
                        else {
                            currentDir = x
                        }
                    })
          result = directs.join("/") //what else do I Do?!
                    return result
                }
                
                function pathify(path) {
                    var newPath = ""
                    if(typeof path == "string") {
                        
                        var slashesDoubled = 0,
                            dotsDoubed
                        path.split("").forEach(x => {
                            var isIts = [
                                "\n"
                            ]
                            if(x == "/") {
                                ++slashesDoubled
                                if(slashesDoubled < 2) newPath += x
                                isIts.push("/")
                            } else {
                                slashesDoubled = 0
                                
                                
                            }
                            if(x == ".") {
                                ++dotsDoubed
                                if(dotsDoubed < 3) newPath += x;
                                isIts.push(".")
                            } else if(
                            1// 
                            ) {
                                dotsDoubed = 0
                                !isIts.includes(x) && (newPath += x)
                            }
                        })
                        var notAtEnd = "/.".split("")
                        if(
                            notAtEnd.includes(newPath[newPath.length - 1])
                        ) {
                            for(var i = newPath.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                if(notAtEnd.includes(newPath[i]))
                                    newPath = newPath.substring(0, newPath.length - 1)
                                else break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return newPath
                }
```

```html
<input id=p><button id=b>Resolve the path!</button><br>
<div id=out></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just split it and reduce it down to a new array. If the segment is `.`, you ignore it, if it's `..` you pop the last segment off your result, otherwise you add it:

```js
const path = "C:/someDir/someOtherDir/someThirdDir/../../folderInSomeDir/fileInFolderInSomeDir.txt";

const result = path.split('/')
                   .reduce((a, v) => {
                     if (v === '.'); // do nothing
                     else if (v === '..') a.pop();
                     else a.push(v);
                     return a;
                   }, [])
                   .join('/');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: perfect, simple enough, it worked great, didn't think to jsut literally take off the last result of the array